# MVC Core app_offline.htm with Web Deploy/FTP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-deployment, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Is it possible to tell Visual Studio 2017 to do the following:

1. Upload app_offline.htm
2. Delete all files
3. Publish website
4. Delete app_offline.htm

I have tried with FTP and Web Deploy but to no avail. The app_offline.htm never gets uploaded. I have it in my root directory of the project and I also added `<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>` under `PropertyGroup`.

I can't seem to find another way to do it when I was looking it up online.